# Pigeon Hole Principle - How many fruit baskets?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Say I have $15$ apples, $20$ bananas, $30$ oranges, and $40$ peaches, and I want to create baskets with at most one of each. How many baskets can have all $4$? I know it's an application of pigeon hole principle, but I am confused about how to go about it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $15, 20,30,$ and $40$ choices for apple, banana, orange, and peach respectively. By multiplication principle, the number of such baskets is $15\times 20\times 30 \times 40 = 360,000$ .